# why I cannot change ListNode?

Tags: python

the definition of listnode is:

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

my code is:

```py
a = ListNode(0)
b = ListNode(0)
a.next = b 

print(a.next) 

cur = b 
cur = ListNode(3)

print(a.next, a.next.val)
```

the output is

```py
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x7fd131f7e910>
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x7fd131f7e910> 0
```

why I couldn't change a.next?

Comment: Changing `cur` to be a different `ListNode` does not change `b`.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this

```
cur = b 
cur = ListNode(3)
```

You set cur to point from `b` to new object `ListNode(3)`. You can see it yourself:

```
print("b   ", b)
print("cur ", cur)
```

But be careful:

```
print("a      ", a.val)
print("a.next ", a.next.val)
print("b      ", b.val, id(b))
print()

b.val = 2  # Both a.next and b points to the same object
print("a      ", a.val)
print("a.next ", a.next.val)
print("b      ", b.val, id(b))
print()

b = ListNode(9) # Now b points to a different object
b.val = 3  # Doesn't effect a.next
print("a      ", a.val)
print("a.next ", a.next.val)
print("b      ", b.val, id(b))
```

```
a       0
a.next  1
b       1 2781116196128

a       0
a.next  2
b       2 2781116196128

a       0
a.next  2
b       3 2781113753264  <--- Notice different id
```

Some keywords to learn about: `mutable vs immutable variables`, `In Python, everything is an object`, [this tutorial on how variables work in python](https://realpython.com/python-variables/#:%7E:text=A%20Python%20variable%20is%20a,still%20contained%20within%20the%20object.)

Python have very different way of handling variables than other languages like C, Java etc. (everything is an object even number like 42) I myself can't fully wrap my head around it